# solution file

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-6

what is solution file in visual c++ 6.0, how to geneate the solution file.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a solution file in VC++ 6.0. In those days, solutions as we know them now were called workspaces and had a file associated with them with a .dsw extension.

Comment: Hmm good old days! :) I remember the term solution somehow pissed me off back then, workspace seemed to be more appropriate. But anyhoo life goes on and now it doesn't sound so bad!

Comment: I like the new name, because now you're creating solutions instead of work ;)